# Adjust ulimit [open file handle limit] on Mac OS X Sierra to run GATK tools

Tags: macos, unix, bioinformatics, macos-sierra, ulimit

I'm trying to run the [VariantsToBinaryPed](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/3.8-0/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_variantutils_VariantsToBinaryPed.php) tool from GATK3, but it seems that my system's 'open file handle limit' is too small for it to successfully run.

I've tried increasing the limit using `ulimit`, as shown below, but the command still fails.

The GATK command:

```
 > java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
   -T VariantsToBinaryPed \
   -R Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta \
   -V  ~/vcf/snp.indel.recal.splitMA_norm.vcf.bgz\
   -m ~/03_IdentityCheck/KING/targeted_seq_ped_clean.fam\
   -bed output.bed\
   -bim output.bim\
   -fam output.fam\
   --minGenotypeQuality 0
```

Returns this error:

```
ERROR MESSAGE: An error occurred because there were too many files 
open concurrently; your system's open file handle limit is probably too small.  
See the unix ulimit command to adjust this limit or 
ask your system administrator for help.
```

Following the advice given [here](http://blog.mact.me/2014/10/22/yosemite-upgrade-changes-open-file-limit), I ran:

```
echo kern.maxfiles=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo kern.maxfilesperproc=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
sudo ulimit -n 65536 65536
```

and added this line to my `.bash_profile` and sourced it:

```
ulimit -n 65536 65536
```

So that now, when I run `ulimit -n`, I get:

`65536`

However, I still get the same error from GATK:

```
ERROR MESSAGE: An error occurred because there were too many files 
open concurrently; your system's open file handle limit is probably too small.  
See the unix ulimit command to adjust this limit or 
ask your system administrator for help.
```

Is there anything else I can do to avoid this error?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persistently-control-maximum-system-resource-consumption-on-mac/221988#221988

Comment: Thanks - I did follow the instructions on that answer, but GATK still fails to run the command successfully on my Mac... I've had to resort to using their Docker image.

Comment: It is very possible that macOS does not allow large enough values to handle this. It is not designed as a server-like OS, which is the usual reason to need so many open files (not in this case, but it's the usual reason).

Comment: I would try posting this issue on the [gatk forums](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/).  Some one there my have more information.